# Use integer for bin

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this code

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"num":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 2), (2,3), (3,6)])
df['bin']=pd.cut(df.num, bins, labels=False)
```

The result is

```
    num bin
0   1   (0, 2]
1   2   (0, 2]
2   3   (2, 3]
3   4   (3, 6]
4   5   (3, 6]
5   6   (3, 6]
```

but I hope the result to be

```
    num bin
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   5   3
5   6   3
```

i.e., use an integer to represent the bin range, how to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out `df['bin_num']=df['bin'].cat.codes+1` will do